# Need to write a program to sanely configure a login shell

Tags: bash, shell

I just started using a Solaris 10 (Sparc) box where I telnet in and get confronted with a very unfriendly interface (compared to the standard bash shell I use in cygwin or linux) --- the arrow keys do not work as I expect them to.  Being an NIS system, changing the shell is not as easy as using the "chsh" command.  And setting the SHELL environment variable in ~/.login and ~/.profile is not working for me.  So I'm thinking that I may need to write a script to determine if bash is running the script and starting bash if the answer is no.  My first attempt, trying to invoke /bin/bash from ~/.profile seems to work but kind of doesn't feel right.  Other suggestions? And how do I tell programmatically which shell is actually executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell what shell is running with `echo $0`.  For example:

```
$ echo $0   
-bash
```

If you're changing shell you probably want to replace the current shell process rather than be a child of it, so use `exec`.

Also, you want to [pass `bash` the `-l` flag so it acts as if it has been called as part of the login process](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash).

So you'll want something like:

```
exec bash -l
```

Comment: +1 on "exec bash -l" but how to I prevent the recursion?  Here's what I wrote:
...
if [ "$0" != "-bash" ] ; then
  echo Starting bash...
  exec bash -l
fi

and when I run this it continues to spawn new bash processes. :-(

Comment: Sorry for the squished script shown in the previous comment.  The actual code is correctly formatted.

Comment: If seems $0 returns "bash" if it's not a log in shell so try: 

if [ "$0" != "-bash" -a "$0" != "bash" ]; then

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: Instead of matching $0, which is not very reliable, you can check for a bash-specific variable: [ -z "$BASH_VERSION" ] || exec bash -l

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running with `ksh(1)` on Solaris.  You have several options, read the manpage for ksh and configure it or install another shell you're more familiar with like bash.  I'd personnaly recommend zsh.

Comment: I like your advice about installing another shell I'm more familiar with.  Bash would be good.  How does one do that in a NIS environment?

Comment: Look on your system for the ypchsh program (/usr/sbin or something close). Check /etc/shells for valid shells and use ypchsh to change your login shell to bash.  If bash is not here, install (or ask your admin to do it).

As a last resort you could compile and install bash in your $HOME/bin and use that "exec $HOME/bin/bash" in .profile...